# Eclipse CDT/CSFML, error while loading shared libraries

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries, eclipse-cdt, sfml

I use Kubuntu 14.04, Eclipse CDT and like to include CSFML which generate this error:

```
/home/u123/Prog/Test/Debug/Test: error while loading shared libraries: libcsfml-audio.so.2.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

my compiler settings:

```
-DCSFML_STATIC -I/home/u123/Prog/CSFML-2.2/include -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0
```

my linker settings

```
 -L/home/u123/Prog/CSFML-2.2/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Xlinker -rpath /home/u123/Prog/SFML-2.2/lib
```

some output of ldconfig -v

```
 /home/u123/Prog/CSFML-2.2/lib:
    libcsfml-system.so.2.2 -> libcsfml-system.so.2.2.0
    libcsfml-graphics.so.2.2 -> libcsfml-graphics.so.2.2.0
    libcsfml-window.so.2.2 -> libcsfml-window.so.2.2.0
    libcsfml-audio.so.2.2 -> libcsfml-audio.so.2.2.0
```

directorys:

```
u123@PC-Ubuntu:~$ ls /home/u123/Prog/CSFML-2.2/lib
libcsfml-audio.so        libcsfml-graphics.so        libcsfml-network.so        libcsfml-system.so        libcsfml-window.so
libcsfml-audio.so.2.2    libcsfml-graphics.so.2.2    libcsfml-network.so.2.2    libcsfml-system.so.2.2    libcsfml-window.so.2.2
libcsfml-audio.so.2.2.0  libcsfml-graphics.so.2.2.0  libcsfml-network.so.2.2.0  libcsfml-system.so.2.2.0  libcsfml-window.so.2.2.0

u123@PC-Ubuntu:~$ ls /home/u123/Prog/SFML-2.2/lib
libsfml-audio.so        libsfml-graphics.so.2.2.0  libsfml-system.so                 libsfml-window.so.2.2.0
libsfml-audio.so.2.2.0  libsfml-network.so         libsfml-system.so.2.2.0  pkgconfig
libsfml-graphics.so     libsfml-network.so.2.2.0   libsfml-window.so
```

ldd:

```
u123@PC-Ubuntu:~$ ldd /home/u123/Prog/Test/Debug/Test
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffec7bfe000)
    libcsfml-graphics.so.2.2 => /home/u123/Prog/CSFML-2.2/lib/libcsfml-graphics.so.2.2 (0x00007f226358b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f22631c6000)
    libsfml-graphics.so.2.2.0 => not found
    libsfml-window.so.2.2.0 => not found
    libsfml-system.so.2.2.0 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f2262ec0000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f2262caa000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055fd8c8fb000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f22629a3000)
```

In my opinion (but i'm not very experienced in SFML) CSFML is code in c, like a facade, which refer to the SFML c++ code.

Any ideas into where the problem lies? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't a `C` missing in your rpath?

Comment: No, imho CSFML need a link to SFML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Enviroment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH solved the problem.
Go to

> Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Enviroment, and add a new variable named LD_LIBRARY_PATH, value = /path/to/lib

in this case /home/u123/Progs/SFML-2.2/lib

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a typo in your `rpath` option,

   `-rpath /home/u123/Prog/SFML-2.2/lib`  should be
   `-rpath /home/u123/Prog/CSFML-2.2/lib` ?
2. Also, try add `-lcsfml-audio` to the linker.

Comment: thx, but imho it isn't a typo, CSFML need a link to SFML. csfml-audio is already in the linker libraries under Preferences->C/C++ Build->Settings->Cross GCC Linker-> Libraries

Comment: 1. Do you mean both dir exists? what's the output of `ls /home/u123/Prog/CSFML-2.2/lib ; ls /home/u123/Prog/SFML-2.2/lib `?2. That is not what the linker settings you posted shows, why not post entire options?

Comment: Sorry, i just post the eclipse "all options" for the compiler and linker, should i better post screenshots of every window?

Comment: Ok, I see, so as you said, one dir is a link to another, that should be good. What's the output of `ldd /home/u123/Prog/Test/Debug/Test`?

Comment: It has both libsfml-graphics.so.2.2.0 and libsfml-graphics.so.2.2, and it can find one, not the other, that's weird. What's the replationship of dir CSFML and SFML and eacho of their files? Their files are not exactly the same,  they are not linked, right?

Comment: I edited my post again. I think you're right and they aren't linked